# Get current user's home directory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm developing a Cocoa Objective-C application that will run on Mac OS X. I need to get the full path of the current user's home directory:

```
/Users/MyUser/
```

Is there a standard function that does that in Objective-C/Cocoa?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[`NSHomeDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1413045-nshomedirectory?language=objc): “Returns the path to the current user’s home directory.”

Example:

```
NSLog(@"Current user’s home directory is %@", NSHomeDirectory());
```

Comment: Swift: print("Current user’s home directory is \\(NSHomeDirectory())")

Answer (score 5):

Since macOS 10.12 you can also use `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser`, see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1642807-homedirectoryforcurrentuser).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser -> URL` or `NSHomeDirectory() -> String` - they both return the same thing, just in different types.

There's an important caveat, though:

> In macOS, it is the application’s sandbox directory or the current user’s home directory (if the application is not in a sandbox).

If you're building your app to be distributed in the App Store, you're going to have to deal with the fact that these functions return the sandboxed home and not the directory the user thinks of as `~`.