# Getting path to users Library folder in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, nssavepanel, appstore-sandbox

I need to open a NSSavePanel with the users Library folder as destination folder. Normally I would do this by entering `~/Library/` in `[NSSavePanel beginSheetForDirectory]`.

This works fine as long as the application is not sandboxed. For sandboxed applications this will result in the `NSSavePanel` trying to access a folder inside the applications document "box".

I cannot refer to `/Users/username/Library/` as I do not know the users `username` at runtime. So how do I link to this path in cocoa?

Comment: If all you want to do is find the user's home dir see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958448/can-i-get-the-current-users-home-directory-in-a-cocoa-objective-c-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work on a sandboxed application but this is how I do it right now. This will return /User/TheirUserName

```
-(NSString *)homeDirectory
{
    return NSHomeDirectory();
}
```

Comment: `NSHomeDirectory()` returns in-sandbox path, at least on 10.7.4. However, while this is the proper method for getting a HOME folder, this is the improper way to fetch the LIBRARY folder. What if the path changes? Please use JWWalker's solution of `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()`. Iterate over all returned elements whenever possible.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure how sandboxing fits in with this, but you can find the user's library directory using:

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to achieve.

- If the behavior is required by your application, then you can request a [temporary exception entitlement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW1) when submitting the application to the Mac App Store. But sooner or later, you will have to find a solution to remove this exception.
- If you want to access data that were previously stored in the `~/Library/` folder, you can define a [migration strategy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingALegacyApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH6-SW1) to move back the data into the sandbox.

Comment: I do not need any elevated entitlements to achive this. It is enough to have read/write on the file system, as I use a save dialog to do the actual saving. I have run a proof of concept on this and know that works.

What I need the user to do, is to save some files in this folder. That is why I need the actual folder and not just access to it's content. So it is no good to bring the data into my sandbox either.

So I need some kind of way to read the users "username" to be able to build up the path to his Library folder, like: "~/user/[username]/Library/