# Accessing User Library folder in Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, plist, osx-mountain-lion

I'm writing a simple preference pane app that will not be on the MAS and does not need to be sandboxed.

I am trying to get access to their user/library directory, or at least find the path.

I can do it this way:

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/USERNAME/Library/";
```

if I know their USERNAME, which I don't know how to get? Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Consider just using NSUserDefaults if you can... [In the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html)

Comment: I want access to the library so I can modify pLists that are in that directory (specifically, user defaults for what application opens what).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting path to users Library folder in OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993319/getting-path-to-users-library-folder-in-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

You can get username by calling NSUserName() function.

UPD: Understand question in wrong way. Please, use this function

```
// Obtain the user's real home directory
// Normally the sandbox returns the app container's user home folder, not the real one
+ (NSString *)homeDirectory {
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:pw->pw_dir];
}
```